# How to determine if returned pointer is on the stack or heap

Tags: c++, c, memory

I have a plugin architecture, where I call functions in a dynamic library and they return me a `char*` which is the answer, it is used at some later stage.

This is the signature of a plugin function:

```
char* execute(ALLOCATION_BEHAVIOR* free_returned_value, unsigned int* length);
```

where `ALLOCATION_BEHAVIOR` must be either: `DO_NOT_FREE_ME`, `FREE_ME`, `DELETE_ME` where the plugin (in the library) tells me how the plugin allocated the string it has just returned: `DO_NOT_FREE_ME` tells me, this is a variable I'm not supposed to touch (such as a `const static char*` which never changes) `FREE_ME` tells me I should use `free()` to free the returned value and `DELETE_ME` tells me to use `delete[]` to get rid of the memory leaks.

Obviously, I don't trust the plugins, so I would like to be able to check that if he tells me to `free()` the variable, indeed it is something that can really be freed ... Is this possible using todays' C/C++ technology on Linux/Windows?

Comment: In a normally designed software, resource management is not as you explained. It should be clear who and when release resources.

Comment: Have you ever failed to free() the resource?

Comment: If you don't trust plugins, don't load them.

Comment: even if its on the heap how will you **trust** whether `FREE_ME` allocated or `DELETE_ME` allocated? if you `delete` something that was not allocated by a previous new then its UB per `3.7.4.2/3`.

Comment: * Obviously, I don't trust the plugins...* If that's the case, why are you using them?

Comment: @DavidHammen I don't trust the plugins, because they are third party plugins. They can be developed by someone in a different company and I never will see the code of them. I must blindly believe they behave as expected. But they might not ...

Comment: @Koushik the plugin "writer" tells me via `ALLOCATION_BEHAVIOR* free_returned_value` if he new'd or malloc'd the data ...

Comment: @BЈовић this is not a normally designed software :) it is a plugin framework which has to manage the data allocated by its plugins. If you have some better alternative I'd be more than happy to hear it, I'm struggling with this for some time ...

Comment: @fritzone No. Apparently, the plugin writer doesn't tell you anything. That seems to be your problem. If they did tell you something you would not have to figure it out by yourself. Your requirements are conflicting: you want the plugin writer to give you this information, and as soon as you get it, you want to discard it and discover it by yourself. Make up your mind and your problem will go away.

Comment: I hate designs like this.  I prefer opaque/translucent libs/plugins to return an object with a virtual 'release()' method so that the plugin handles the deletion/repool/whatever of the data when no longer required.  The code in the plugin can override 'release()' however it wishes.

Comment: Also... How the heck would the plugin allocate something "on the stack" and **return** a valid pointer to it? Are you supporting [book thievery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) plugins?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - you could pop the resturn address from the stack, allocate the local stack data, then jump to the return address with the data pointer.  How the free() function would then work is another matter :)

Comment: When I designed a plugin system, we used c-isms. The plugin was asked to create and return a valid pointer (`create_foo`). It also contained it's own `delete_foo` function. The owning program would call that and pass the pointer back to the plugin for destruction. This lets your code control the lifetime of the pointer, but shoves the responsibility for malloc/free, new/delete, or pointer-to-static/nothing off on the plugin dev.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Distinguishing between `malloc/free` and `new/delete` is generally not possible, at least not in a reliable and/or portable way. Even more so as `new` simply wrapps `malloc` anyway in many implementations.

None of the following alternatives to distinguish heap/stack have been tested, but they *should* all work.

**Linux:**

1. Solution proposed by Luca Tettananti, parse `/proc/self/maps` to get the address range of the stack.
2. As the first thing at startup, `clone` your process, this implies *supplying* a stack. Since you supply it, you automatically know where it is.
3. Call GCC's `__builtin_frame_address` function with increasing *level* parameter until it returns 0. You then know the depth. Now call `__builtin_frame_address` again with the maximum level, and once with a level of 0. Anything that lives on the stack must necessarily be between these two addresses.
4. `sbrk(0)` as the first thing at startup, and remember the value. Whenever you want to know if something is on the heap, `sbrk(0)` again -- something that's on the heap must be between the two values. Note that this will not work reliably with allocators that use memory mapping for large allocations.

Knowing the location and size of the stack (alternatives 1 and 2), it's trivial to find out if an address is within that range. If it's not, is necessarily "heap" (unless someone tries to be super smart-ass and gives you a pointer to a static global, or a function pointer, or such...).

**Windows:**

1. Use [CaptureStackBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), anything living on the stack must be between the returned pointer array's first and last element.
2. Use GCC-MinGW (and `__builtin_frame_address`, which should just work) as above.
3. Use `GetProcessHeaps` and `HeapWalk` to check every allocated block for a match. If none match for none of the heaps, it's consequently allocated on the stack (... or a memory mapping, if someone tries to be super-smart with you).
4. Use `HeapReAlloc` with `HEAP_REALLOC_IN_PLACE_ONLY` and with exactly the same size. If this fails, the memory block starting at the given address is not allocated on the heap. If it "succeeds", it is a no-op.
5. Use `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` (Windows 8 / 2012 only)
6. Call `NtCurrentTeb()` (or read `fs:[18h]`) and use the fields `StackBase` and `StackLimit` of the returned TEB.

Comment: I'll accept this, because it gave me the closest answer of what the question was.

Answer (score 8):

I did the same question a couple of years ago on comp.lang.c, I liked the response of James Kuyper:

> Yes. Keep track of it when you allocate it.
>
> The way to do this is to use the concept of ownership of memory. At
>   all times during the lifetime of a block of allocated memory, you
>   should always have one and only one pointer that "owns" that block.
>   Other pointers may point into that block, but only the owning pointer
>   should ever be passed to free().
>
> If at all possible, an owning pointer should be reserved for the
>   purpose of owning pointers; it should not be used to store pointers to
>   memory it does not own. I generally try to arrange that an owning
>   pointer is initialized with a call to malloc(); if that's not
>   feasible, it should be set to NULL sometime before first use. I also
>   try to make sure that the lifetime of an owning pointer ends
>   immediately after I free() the memory it owns. However, when that's
>   not possible, set it to NULL immediately after free()ing that memory.
>   With those precautions in place, you should not let the lifetime of a
>   non-null owning pointer end without first passing it to free().
>
> If you have trouble keeping track of which pointers are 'owning'
>   pointers, put a comment about that fact next to their declaration. If
>   you have lots of trouble, use a naming convention to keep track of
>   this feature.
>
> If, for any reason, it is not possible to reserve an owning pointer
>   variable exclusively for ownership of the memory it points at, you
>   should set aside a separate flag variable to keep track of whether or
>   not that pointer currently owns the memory it points at. Creating a
>   struct that contains both the pointer and the ownership flag is a very
>   natural way to handle this - it ensures that they don't get separated.
>
> If you have a rather complicated program, it may be necessary to
>   transfer ownership of memory from one owning pointer variable to
>   another. If so, make sure that any memory owned by target pointer is
>   free()d before the transfer, and unless the lifetime of the source
>   pointer ends immediately after the transfer, set the source pointer to
>   NULL. If you're using ownership flags, reset them accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin/library/whatever should not be returning an enum through a passed 'ALLOCATION_BEHAVIOR*' pointer.  It's messy, at best. The 'deallocation' scheme belongs with the data and should be encapsulated with it.

I would prefer to return an object pointer of some base class that has a virtual 'release()' function member that the main app can call whenever it wants/needs to and handles the 'dealloaction' as required for that object.  release() could do nothing, repool the object in a cache specified in a private data memebr of the object, of just delete() it, depending on whatever override is applied by the plugin subclasses.

If this is not possible because the plugin is written in a different language, or built with a different compiler, the plugin could return a function as well as the data so that the main app can call it back with the data pointer as a parameter for the purpose of deallocation.  This at least allows you to put the char* and function* into the same object/struct on the C++ side, so maintaining at least some semblance of encapsulation and allowing the plugin to choose any deallocation scheme it wants to.

Edit - a scheme like this would also work safely if the plugin used a different heap than the main app - maybe it's in a DLL that has its own sub-allocator.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can parse `/proc/self/maps` to extract the location of the stack and of the heap and then check whether the pointer falls into one of ranges.

This won't tell you if the memory should be handled by free or delete though. If you control the architecture you can let the plugin free the allocated memory adding the appropriate API (IOW, a `plugin_free` function that is symmetrical to your `execute`). Another common pattern is to keep track of the allocations in a context object (created at init time) that is passed to the plugin at each call and is then used by the plugin at shutdown to do the clean up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code to check student assignments. Returning stack memory is a common pitfall, so I wanted to automatically check for it.

## Using `sbrk`

This method should work on all Unix variants and on all CPU architectures.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

bool points_to_heap(void* init_brk, void* pointer){
    void* cur_brk = sbrk(0);
    return ((init_brk <= pointer) && (pointer <= cur_brk));
}

int main(void){
    void* init_brk = sbrk(0);
    int* heapvar = malloc(10);
    int i = 0;
    int* stackvar = &i;
    assert(points_to_heap(init_brk, heapvar));
    assert(!points_to_heap(init_brk, stackvar));
    return 0;
}
```

## Using `/proc/self/maps`

Two issues with this method:

- This code is specific to Linux running on a 64-bit x86 CPU.
- This method doesn't seem to work in unit tests written using the [`libcheck`](https://libcheck.github.io/check/) framework. There, all stack variables are also seen as heap variables.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void get_heap_bounds(uint64_t* heap_start, uint64_t* heap_end){
    FILE *stream;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    stream = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
        if (strstr(line, "[heap]")){
            sscanf(line, "%" SCNx64 "-%" SCNx64 "", heap_start, heap_end);
            break;
        }
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(stream);
}

bool is_heap_var(void* pointer){
    uint64_t heap_start = 0;
    uint64_t heap_end = 0;
    get_heap_bounds(&heap_start, &heap_end);

    if (pointer >= (void*)heap_start && pointer <= (void*)heap_end){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Feedback on this code is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

How do they allocate something on the stack that you can then free, as they've returned? That's just going to die horribly. Even using it is going to die horribly.

If you want to check whether they've returned you pointer to static data, then you probably want to get hold of your heap top and bottom (which I'm pretty sure is available on linux, using sbrk), and see if the returned pointer is in that range or not.

Of course, it's possible that even a valid pointer in that range shouldn't be freed because they've stashed another copy to it which they're going to use later. And if you're not going to trust them, you should not trust them at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use some debugging tools to determine whether the pointer is on stack or on heap.
On windows, download Sysinternals Suite. This provides various tool for debugging.