# Is malloc/realloc/calloc used?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, libc, calloc

For C programmers.

How can I know if a pointer `char *`, for example, was initialized by using `malloc` or `realloc`? I mean in kind of that function:

```
char* func(char** x){
    /* need some reallocating of *x but 
     * *x can be a pointer to const string
     */
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if returned pointer is on the stack or heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709946/how-to-determine-if-returned-pointer-is-on-the-stack-or-heap)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It must be true in most cases.

Comment: realloc can very well use malloc internally. Why do you want to know?

Comment: `realloc` call `malloc` in case of NULL pointer, but I need
"to determine whether a pointer refers to a static or auto variable, or to memory allocated" so it said @JohnBodу. Now for me problem is kind of solved.

Comment: o their address range is different, stack addresses are generally, bigger. look at your architecture and figure out the range or VM addresses that should be your stack/auto variable range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *portable* way to determine whether a pointer refers to a static or auto variable, or to memory allocated via the `*alloc` functions, by looking at the pointer value alone.  If you are *intimately* familiar with the memory model on your platform you could make some educated guesses, but that's about it.

Otherwise, if it matters, you will have to track that information yourself.